# Convert an Xcode iPad app using Cordova (Phonegap) to Android

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cordova

I have just finished an app in Xcode 4.6.3 using Cordova 2.9.0.

The app is JavaScript / HTML / CSS based.

Can anyone recommend software / a forum which had good tutorials on converting apps from iOS on Xcode to Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any kind of software to convert code. you must create new project for andorid

Using PhoneGap you done all your work using only HTML/CSS/JavaScript. PhoneGap has different builds for different architectures and your project is just WebView for architecture you want to. Simply if you need to port your PhoneGap app for Android you need to download project template for Ecllipse and move all your HTML/CSS/JS code into the project. Just remember that portability of PhoneGap is just because of WebView and solid JS interfaces for different phones. You actually does not need to know what lies under PhoneGap just use WWW technologies.

Create Andorid project through [Phonegap andorid](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

Comment: Adobe have created a phonegap build. It is free to use for 1 conversion, but then costs money. **Note**: The maximum zip file size you can upload is 15MB. [https://build.phonegap.com/apps](https://build.phonegap.com/apps)